# Query to exclude row based on another row's filter

Tags: oracle, rows

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Question: How can I write query to return just ID only if ALL the codes for that ID end in 6?

I don't want ID=1 because not all its codes end in 6.

```
TABLE_A

ID  Code
===============
1   100  
1   106
2   206
3   316
3   326
4   444

Desired Result:
ID
==
2
3
```

Comment: Should we assume CODE is a VARCHAR2? Is it restricted to digits, or can it contain non-numerics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want each ID where the count of rows for that id is the same as the count of rows where the third digit is six.

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(code,3,1) = '6' THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: Both Gary Myers and Cybernate offered solutions that worked. I got identical results from both queries. Howver, my Explain Plan cost for Myers' code was 2, the cost from Cybernate's code was 2426.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id
  FROM (
        SELECT id, 
                COUNT(1) cnt
          FROM table_a  
         GROUP BY id 
        ) a,
        (
        SELECT id, 
                COUNT(1) cnt
          FROM table_a  
         WHERE CODE LIKE '%6'
         GROUP BY id
        )b
WHERE a.id = b.id
  AND a.cnt = b.cnt
```

Alternative using ANALYTIC functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id   
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT  id, 
            COUNT(1)  OVER(PARTITION BY id) cnt,
            SUM(CASE WHEN code LIKE '%6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY id) sm
        FROM  table_a 
  )
WHERE cnt = sm
```

Comment: When I see a DISTINCT, my first suspicion is that something is wrong.